# Cannot install libc6 ver 2.29 /newer on debian buster

Tags: debian, glibc

Tried to install libc6 ver 2.29 /newer on debian buster, and did get it:

http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.31-9_amd64.deb

but then

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.31-9_amd64.deb 
dpkg: regarding libc6_2.31-9_amd64.deb containing libc6:amd64:
 libc6:amd64 breaks libgegl-0.4-0 (<< 0.4.18)
  libgegl-0.4-0:amd64 (version 0.4.16-0.1~mx19+1) is present and installed.
```

How to solve such this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not install [`libc6 2.31-9`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libc6) from Debian 11 ( bullseye ) on debian 10 ([`libc6 2.28-10`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libc6)), this will break your system. Upgrading to bullseye is more safe.